# Joomla Jquery Conflict with external javascript

Tags: jquery, joomla, conflict

i have included external HTML FILE using custom code plugin joomla 2.5, and within the html file i linked to external javascript files

`<script src="drop.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

It works fine but unfortunate this javascript conflict my joomla jquery and i cant figure out how to have both loaded at same time.

any advice or help appreciated.

Comment: What errors are showing with tools such as Chrome Dev Tools or Firebug? Do you have multiple versions of jQuery being imported? Can you provide a link to the site? Why are you loading an external `html` file which is loading a `js` file? What does this `html` file contain that can't be properly inserted into the site?

Comment: Use jQuery.noConflict, Refer this article, may help you http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

Comment: Hi, ok i add the java script using

JHTML::script('drop.js', ''); in the head.php of the template and guess what it works perfectly, but still the conflict isnt resolved, please help, its the YOOTHEME widgetkit Jquery that is not showing up

Comment: Be careful, yootheme has a javascript compressor so check the sequence in your rendered html to make sure jQuery is the first line, then jQuery.noConflict, then the rest. Also once you do noconflict, $ may be set to mootools, so drop.js would need to be invoked with jQuery not the shorthand $

Comment: Create a fiddle so it is easy to help you